# How to develop an app that integrates Google Home with Login using Node.js, Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, actions-on-google, google-home

I have been making Google Home apps, but now I want to make apps that are connected to Firebase server and DialogFlow API. How is it possible to integrate user authentication in an ios app to identify that user who is using Google Home with that login state?

For example, if I make a restaurant ordering app, I want any user to make a request through Google Home and the user can check his/her ordering history on an ios app.

A user logs in through an app and then how does google home detect that user as a logged in user? I have been searching how to implement this, but nothing hits.

Comment: Question is too broad and doesn't specify any concrete technical problem encountered during your current work covered so far. Try specifying what exactly have you already tried to integrate and when you actually hit the wall. There are also other already answered questions on SO related to Firebase Authentication, did you check them out?

Comment: Okay, I’ll update that later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) for Actions on Google. This will require two server-side components that you'll need to build:

1. You'll need to create an OAuth server that will allow the user to authenticate to your service (and use Firebase auth as a component of this) and authorize the Google Assistant to access your service. It does this by generating tokens that it hands to the Assistant.
2. Your Dialogflow fulfillment webhook will get this token passed to it as part of the conversation. It uses this token to determine which user is making the request and confirm it is valid.

There are OAuth services that are available that work with Google's auth that you should be able to fit in here, or you can write your own using Firebase Hosting and Firebase Cloud Functions. The Dialogflow webhook can, of course, be done using Firebase Cloud Functions.